# Looking for "minimum viable English utterances" to provide sufficient phoneme coverage for TTS training

Tags: english, models

There are quite a lot of really, really large utterance/phoneme datasets out there, but I can't seem to find anything small. I'm looking for the minimum viable set of utterances/sentences in English that would provide sufficient coverage of phonemes so that, if you fed them all into a training algorithm, you could get a half-decent model. I don't actually want any audio data, because I'm going to generate that myself (custom voice model).

Answer (score 0):

Someone shared: https://github.com/rhasspy/tts-prompts

This looks great!

Ref: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/minimum-viable-english-phoneme-coverage-set-ljspeech-style/86854 (also my post)